# IPW for the effect of treatment on treated with a continuous treatment

Tags: causality, propensity-scores

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to construct inverse probability of treatment weights (IPTW) for the population average effect of treatment on treated (PATT) with a continuous treatment.

The literature always seems to stop short of a worked example. For example, [Hernán and Robins, in the appendix](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2652882/), or [in Technical Point 4.1 on page 46](https://cdn1.sph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/1268/2019/02/hernanrobins_v1.10.38.pdf), are quite clear conceptually about how to estimate $Pr[Y_a = 1 | A = a']$ where $a \neq a'$ with weights:

$$\frac{Pr[A = a'|L]}{f(A|L)}$$

Were $a$ is the treatment value, $L$ is a vector of confounders, and $f(A|L)$ is the conditional probability density function of $A$ given $L$.

For the population average treatment effect (PATE), the numerator is 1 or some stabilizer like the unconditional probability of treatment, and the denominator is $f(A|L)$.

But for the PATT, I'm stuck. I’m not sure whether it’s a tweak to which observations I model, which observations I use to predict fitted values, which fitted values I use in the probability density function, or how I assign PDFs of treatment.

For dichotomous treatment PATT, it's easy: Treated are weighted 1 and untreated are  weighted $\frac{Pr[Treatment]}{1-Pr[Treatment]}$.  But since nobody is really "untreated" in the continuous scenario, I'm not sure how to extend the logic.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: The concept of PATT doesn't exist for continuous treatments. You estimate the average dose-response function (ADRF) with continuous treatments. What kind of substantive conclusion are you trying to draw that would lead you to want this estimand?

Comment: A super reductionist example: Income is the "exposure" and mortality is the outcome. Higher income causes lower mortality. It's not really relevant whether the risk in richer people, had they been poorer, equals the risk in those who were actually poorer. It's more relevant whether the risk in poorer people, had they been richer, equals the risk in people who were actually richer.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and is an interesting problem. Basically, you want to define a target population and then estimate the ADRF for that population rather than estimating it for the overall population from which your sample was drawn. You can estimate standard IPW weights for continuous treatments and then apply transportation weights to change the target population. You can also directly target a population using my `optweight` package, which estimates balancing weights directly that make the treatment uncorrelated with the covariates.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  I'll be sure to check out `optweight`!

Comment: Just know that no research has been done on this method with continuous treatments. It's the topic of my dissertation.